# Tracking Software Issues Separate from Sprint Tasks in YouTrack

Tags: youtrack

My team is currently using YouTrack to manage our sprint tasks, which include both software-issue related tasks and non-software-issue related tasks, and a separate issue tracking program that just keeps track of issues with our software.  This makes connecting sprint tasks to software issues (ie fix bug in X program) difficult.

As a result, we want to try and merge our software-issue tracking into our YouTrack project—but we can't think of a great way to go about doing so.

From what I can tell, our only real option for doing so would be to import our software issues into our YouTrack project's database, but tag them with something like "software-issue" and the non-software issues as "sprint-tasks". At that point, we could create separate views to look at the issues tagged "software-issues" and "sprint-tasks".

That said, we keep track of slightly different information for our software issues and our sprint tasks. We could expand the database so that every sprint task has the needed properties for both the sprint task data and the software issue data, but just ignore the software issue-specific properties for our sprint tasks and vice versa. That seems a bit ugly to me, though.

Does anyone have any thoughts on the cleanest and simplest way we could go about this? Is there a way to easily link YouTrack items from one YouTrack project in another YouTrack project's tasks? Or an issue tracking system that integrates well with YouTrack?

Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, keeping all the issues in Youtrack makes the most sense, as it should make your whole working process much easier.

As for distinguishing issues, I see the following solutions depending on your requirements:

- [create separate projects](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/Create-New-Project.html) for software and non-software issues
- [use a custom field](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/Custom-Fields.html) to indicate the type of the issue. For example, use the Type field or something like that and have the values that would correspond with the type of the task.
- use [tags](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/Using-Tags.html#create-tag) as you described yourself

I think that the custom field approach would be the best here. It gives you a lot of options in [managing the board](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/Agile-Board.html) with sprints. For example, you can base swimlanes on the field value, thus dividing the tasks on a single board. Alternatively, you can use the values to automatically create sprints and have tasks on separate sprints. And, of course, you can indicate the field value when creating a board and thus put tasks with different values on different boards.